# Using a download manager to download from an MSDN subscription

Tags: download-manager, msdn

I'm an MSDN subscriber and I'd like to download a large file from there (~3.5 GB).

- Downloading straight from FireFox is problematic as it would stop after a few hundred megabytes.
- Downloading from IE10 and Chrome is too slow.
- There's supposed to be an automatic ActiveX "Akamai Download Manager" for MSDN downloads but apparently it isn't configured for this download (the ActiveX pane never pops up, even after the steps [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/help/genuine/ie-activex)).

I tried using FlashGot to route it to FDM (Free Download Manager) but I get:

```
Access denied. Invalid user name or password
```

I tried setting my MSDN user/pass in the download properties, to no avail. Is there some way to get this to work in a decent download manager (doesn't have to be FDM)?

Comment: Personal or company computer?

Comment: Personal computer

Comment: wget gets "403 forbidden"

Comment: Might want to determine what's making Firefox quit the download

Comment: Well I've always had that with big downloads, I was under the impression that it was common knowledge for browser downloads to be unreliable. Otherwise why have download managers ?

Comment: Have you tried Internet Download Manger? If not its a worth to give a shot to it. If it doesn't cacth the url automatically then try to add the address manually. Start the download in Chrome, open the download mander page in Chrome copy link url and add in IDM. It works for me most of the time if it doesn't catch theurl aautomatically.

Comment: @avirk - thanks for the suggestion. For now I was able to download it via FireFox, but I'll give it a try if I have the need in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of March 2015, MSDN has discontinued the use of the Microsoft File Transfer Manager. They recommend using a 3rd party download manager or the browser's built-in download functionality. [See the link here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/subscriptions/aa948864.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

MSDN can use Microsoft File Transfer Manager to download files, but it doesn't launch properly in IE11.

The solution in http://stealthpuppy.com/work-around-for-getting-file-transfer-manager-to-download-from-technetmsdn/ to get File Transfer Manager to launch worked for me:

1. For Internet Explorer 11, press F12 to bring up the developer tools window
2. Click the Emulation icon (bottom left) or press Ctrl+8
3. Select ’9′ under Document Mode
4. Choose ‘Internet Explorer 9′ under User Agent String

Comment: Trying to get this method to work on Win 8 + IE 11, but it's not happening. Can you check again please? Maybe they've made some server side changes as Dirk Strauss points out.

Answer (score 4):

The [DownThemAll-Addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/downthemall/) for firefox works well with MSDN. Also it allows to download with a much faster speed than with many other download-helpers.

**Update**

It's very easy to use. Only start the download. Than in the window where you can set the download-path, there will be a downthemall-option. Maybe you have to write in the username and your password again.

Comment: and works as built in. indeed a good choice, along with pipelining for speed.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. Still 403 error.

Comment: The problem maybe could be solved by clearing ALL browser history (cache,  etc). Then restart firefox.

Answer (score 2):

Visit the MSDN site in Internet Explorer 9 and you get the option to download the file through the Microsoft File Transfer Manager. You can pause transfers and the transfer rate will be much higher.

You can also visit the site in IE11 in IE9 document mode (use the [Internet Explorer's F12 Developers Tools](http://www.sitepoint.com/ie11-browser-modes-return/) feature)